# How to handle the postgres connection when heroku changes the DATABASE_URL

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres, node-postgres

On [Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)  there is written:

> The value of your app’s `DATABASE_URL` config var might change at any time. You should not rely on this value either inside or outside your Heroku app.

I'm developing a Node.js server that uses [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com) to connect and manage the connection pool with the database.

But what happens when Heroku changes the `DATABASE_URL`? How should this problem be managed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You handle this by always connecting to Postgres using whatever value `DATABASE_URL` has. For example, you can use this value as a [connection string](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting#connection-uri) when you create your pool:

```
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: connectionString,
})
```

Heroku's dynos [restart when their environment variables or addons are changed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts), which should cause your code to pick up the new database connection string when it starts back up.

Comment: I already use the environment variable.  But some things are not clear to me:
`pool = new Pool ({connectionString: connectionString})` it is executed only the first time, after which, when a new connection is needed, it is searched among those already active and available, otherwise a new one is established. So the questions are immediate: 1) How does connectionString capture the change?  2) What happens to the connections already active in the Pool?

Comment: @alessiovolpe, when the variable changes your dyno should restart and pick up the new setting. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Now I understand, otherwise I couldn't explain how the thing could be handled at run time. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have `preboot` enabled, heroku will not change the env and will *not* restart your dyno. Just confirmed this with Heroku support.